How to pass the date
I started with this question about how to add a calendar.  I've run it and it pretty much does exactly what I need.
I am trying to modify it so that it passes the date to a cell and then closes.  I have limited knowledge of VBA.  ie I have no clue what #if is compared to if.  Last time I had any formal programing training was Turbo Pascal in about 1992.  I know there are Global and Local variable.  So I was trying to figure out the proper way to pass the picked date back to the cell.  My current approach is:
Sheet2 "Forecast" Code
Private Sub StartDatePicker_Click()
    
Dim StartDate As Date

    CalendarModule.Launch (StartDate)
    Me.Cells(5, 2) = StartDate
End Sub

Private Sub EndDatePicker_Click()
        
Dim EndDate As Date
    CalendarModule.Launch (EndDate)
    Me.Cells(6, 2) = EndDate
End Sub

CalendarModule Code
Sub Launch(dDate As Date)
    Set f = frmCalendar
    
    With f
        .Caltheme = ArcticBlue
        .LongDateFormat = "dddd dd. mmmm yyyy" '"dddd mmmm dd, yyyy" etc
        .ShortDateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"  '"mm/dd/yyyy" or "d/m/y" etc
        .Show
    End With
End Sub

frmCalendar code
'~~> Insert Selected date
Private Sub DTINSERT_Click()

Dim PickedDate as Date
    If Len(Trim(Label6.Caption)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a date first", vbCritical, "No date selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '~~> Change the code here to insert date where ever you want
    'PickedDate = Cdate(Label6.Caption)
    MsgBox Label6.Caption, vbInformation, "Date selected"
End Sub

Question
I am not familiar at all with working with forms.  How do I pass PickedDate back to CalendarModule.Launch then back to Sheet2.StartDatePicker_Click and then run it again and return it to Sheet2.EndDatPicker_Click
Update 24/09/29 11:20
I placed the following in the frmCalendar code:
Public PickedDate as Date

I have the code in the CalendarModule as follows:
Sub Launch(dDate As Date)
    Set f = frmCalendar
    
    With f
        .Caltheme = ArcticBlue
        .LongDateFormat = "dddd dd. mmmm yyyy" '"dddd mmmm dd, yyyy" etc
        .ShortDateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"  '"mm/dd/yyyy" or "d/m/y" etc
        .Show
        dDate = .PickedDate
    End With
End Sub

dDate takes the value of the date selected which is great, but when it get back to sheet2 code, it has a value of zero:
Private Sub StartDatePicker_Click()
    
Dim StartDate As Date

    CalendarModule.Launch (StartDate)
    Me.Cells(5, 2) = StartDate
    
End Sub

I feel I am missing some sort of declaration in the Sub Launch (dDate as Date) line.

You can declare a public variable in the frmCalendar:
Public PickedDate as Date

Then
Sub Launch(dDate As Date)
    Set f = frmCalendar
    
    With f
        .PickedDate = initial value
        .Caltheme = ArcticBlue
        .LongDateFormat = "dddd dd. mmmm yyyy" '"dddd mmmm dd, yyyy" etc
        .ShortDateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"  '"mm/dd/yyyy" or "d/m/y" etc
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Cells(5, 2) = .PickedDate
    End With
End Sub

But the form should be exit by Me.Hide (it's the code for the Ok or similar button).
Update on OP's update
You need to remove parentheses:
Dim StartDate As Date

    CalendarModule.Launch StartDate
    Me.Cells(5, 2) = StartDate
    
End Sub


Is a Public Variable basically the same thing as a global variable?  ie.  its a variable that can be used in all functions and subs?

No. Such variable declared in a form has lifetime same as the form and accessible only over the form variable (f). Global variables are declared in project modules. A global variable is another way to pass the value to/from the form.

And put On Error Resume Next where I put it. It will prevent an application error in case of top-right cross of the form is clicked.

I learned that neat way of public variable then using .variable for the form.  I never knew that was possible.  I have it working now passing the variable all the way through the various calls.  Thanks for that.  Back to my original question, is passing the variable the standard approach to this king of situation or is the global variable the better approach?

There is no standard approach here. Both ways can be used. But OOP encapsulation requires all variables to be inside the form.
